# Email Alerts Not Working in Kimono

Tags: kimono

The email alert I setup did not notify me when new data was added. I can see the new data on the site, but the email never came through. I have even checked my spam and nothing is there.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the same email as the one in your account information ?
If not try with your account email.

Comment: No I did not. But as they advertise, it should work with any email. I will try with my account email now.